# What can be derived from someone else's Google Analytics id?

Tags: privacy, google

A web page, which I'd expect to respect users' privacy, contains Google Analytics tracker. I consider it to be a wrong thing; before raising this to the site owner, I'd like to do minimal "research". The site is likely built by a subcontractor. I see two concerns:

1. Google gets the data it wants.
2. The analytics script is in fact used by the subcontractor company, not by the site owner; so the subcontractor gets the analytics Google provides.

Thinking on the second one: is it possible to figure out the Google account, which owns the tracking code (UA-xxxxxxxx-xx)?

Does the GA request URL reveal anything else?

Comment: Why is it a "wrong thing"? Is this a specific kind of web-page that demands some higher level of security? By what other means would the site owner get analytics? They probably have asked the contractor to collect and report on their behalf, or just to put their own ID in there.

Comment: @HorusKol _Why is it a "wrong thing"?_ - the web page is in the company intranet. It handles user input, containing company confidential information. Also statistics about requests to particular URLs is confidential.

Comment: If this is a company intranet, and you think the analytics shouldn't be there, don't bother with "research" and go straight to your boss. Either he will take it up with the appropriate people in your organisation, or already be aware of it and tell it isn't a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not reveal anything more than what it is: a pseudonym used by Google to trace some activity wherever it is placed.

You cannot figure out the owner of such pseudonym unless you are Google or have access to Google's database on this (or whoever generated such ID places in some other webpage by mistake and that webpage has personal information that eventually leads to the owner of the Google account, but this is just being careless).

Your scenario of the subcontractor does not need to use Google's ID, they could use other solutions available out there for those who do not want to rely on Google to track their visitors.

Whether tracking users or not is good or bad is another question (and actually more like a discussion).